# How to restore PostgreSQL standby server from archive?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.5, repmgr

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 cluster with `master` and `standby` server that are replicated using `repmgr`. Master is configured to keep `4000` WAL files:

```
wal_level = logical
hot_standby = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /mnt/share/psql/archive/psql/%f && cp %p /mnt/share/psql/archive/psql/%f'
max_worker_processes = 10                        
max_replication_slots = 10
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 4000
```

At some point the `standby` server falls behind master (I have no idea why is this happening):

```
2017-01-28 23:49:24 UTC ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2017-01-28 23:49:24 UTC STATEMENT:  
2017-01-28 23:51:10 UTC LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log segment 0000000200001E5A000000C8, offset 5201920
2017-01-28 23:51:10 UTC LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1E5A/C8000000 on timeline 2
2017-01-29 00:04:59 UTC FATAL:  could not send data to WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
                This probably means the server terminated abnormally
                before or while processing the request.

2017-01-29 00:16:10 UTC LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log segment 0000000200001E5B000000C5, offset 5242880
2017-01-29 00:16:10 UTC LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1E5B/C5000000 on timeline 2
2017-01-29 00:50:07 UTC FATAL:  could not send data to WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
                This probably means the server terminated abnormally
                before or while processing the request.

2017-01-29 00:50:07 UTC LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log segment 0000000200001E5D0000000A, offset 5373952
2017-01-29 00:50:22 UTC LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1E5D/A000000 on timeline 2
2017-01-29 03:29:35 UTC FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000200001E64000000B7 has already been removed
```

Obviously master removed needed WAL `0000000200001E64000000B7`, but the file is still present in the archive.
Anyway, after `standby` restart the database seems to reach consistent state:

```
...
2017-01-29 13:45:35 UTC LOG:  restored log file "0000000200001E64000000B1" from archive
2017-01-29 13:45:36 UTC LOG:  restored log file "0000000200001E64000000B2" from archive
2017-01-29 13:45:36 UTC LOG:  restored log file "0000000200001E64000000B3" from archive
2017-01-29 13:45:36 UTC LOG:  restored log file "0000000200001E64000000B4" from archive
2017-01-29 13:45:37 UTC LOG:  restored log file "0000000200001E64000000B5" from archive
2017-01-29 13:45:37 UTC LOG:  restored log file "0000000200001E64000000B6" from archive
2017-01-29 13:45:37 UTC LOG:  restored log file "0000000200001E64000000B7" from archive
2017-01-29 13:45:38 UTC LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 1E64/B7DFFD78
2017-01-29 13:45:38 UTC LOG:  recovery stopping after reaching consistency
2017-01-29 13:45:38 UTC LOG:  recovery has paused
2017-01-29 13:45:38 UTC HINT:  Execute pg_xlog_replay_resume() to continue.
2017-01-29 13:45:38 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
```

PostgreSQL suggest to execute `pg_xlog_replay_resume()`, but this would lead to promoting standby to master, thus a split-brain situation.

```
$ repmgr cluster show
Role      | Name                    | Upstream                | Connection String
----------+-------------------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------------------
* master  | psql01a                 |                         | host=psql01a user=repmgr
  standby | psql01b                 | psql01a                 | host=psql01b user=repmgr
```

`recovery.conf`:

```
restore_command = 'cp /mnt/share/psql/archive/psql/%f %p'
recovery_target_inclusive = true
recovery_target = 'immediate'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
standby_mode = on
primary_conninfo = 'user=repmgr port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres host=psql01a application_name=psql01b password=ZDIzNjk2OTM2MWYyNjNiYzk5ZDVhMWIw'
recovery_min_apply_delay = 0
```

PostgreSQL 9.5 comes with a new parameter `recovery_target_action` that [can have 3 values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/recovery-target-settings.html) in `recovery.conf`:

- `pause` (default) recovery will be paused
- `shutdown` will stop the server after reaching the recovery target
- `promote` means the recovery process will finish and the server will start to accept connections

`promote` seems to be logical choice according to the documentation, however it leads again to split-brain situation:

```
2017-01-29 19:31:27 UTC LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 1E64/B7DFFD78
2017-01-29 19:31:27 UTC LOG:  recovery stopping after reaching consistency
2017-01-29 19:31:27 UTC LOG:  redo done at 1E64/B7DFFD78
2017-01-29 19:31:27 UTC LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2017-01-29 00:32:06.442239+00
2017-01-29 19:31:27 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
cp: cannot stat '/mnt/share/psql/archive/psql/00000003.history': No such file or directory
2017-01-29 19:31:27 UTC LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 3
cp: cannot stat '/mnt/share/psql/archive/psql/00000002.history': No such file or directory
2017-01-29 19:31:28 UTC LOG:  archive recovery complete

$ repmgr cluster show
Role      | Name                    | Upstream                | Connection String
----------+-------------------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------------------
* master  | psql01a                 |                         | host=psql01a user=repmgr
* master  | psql01b                 | psql01a                 | host=psql01b user=repmgr
```

The question is how to resume WAL streaming without promoting standby to master? Is it possible to do this in an automatic manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify a `recovery_target`.  Then `recovery_target_action` doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Is it good idea to have `recovery.conf` present even in case that replication is working?

Comment: You need it around to set primary_conninfo, and standby_mode.  Those are the only two entries you need if you are purely streaming (not optionally getting from WAL archive as well)